# Combine values from two columns into third where certain conditions are met in Python using np.where

Tags: python, numpy, where-clause

In the following example df, I want to combine values from col c and d into a new col e only when a = 1:

```
a   c   d   
1   ab  xy
0   cd  zf
0   sd  zk
1   df  sd
```

I wrote the following code:

```
df['e'] = np.where(df['a'] == 1, ("ERR: " + df["c"] + " - " + df["d"]', np.NaN)
```

It's not working. I get the following error: *TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "map") to str*

I can solve it by creating a temp column which combines values from the two columns and use that instead. But hoping there's a way to do it directly here if possible.

Solution using temp col:

```
dfCM['b'] = "ERR: " + dfCM["c"] + " - " + dfCM["d"]
df['e'] = np.where(df['a'] == 1, df[b'], np.NaN)
```

Desired result:

```
a   c   d   e
1   ab  xy  ERR: ab-xy
0   cd  zf
0   sd  zk
1   df  sd  ERR: df-sd
```

Thanks

Comment: Okay, solved it. The issue was not with the above code, rather changes upstream had inserted "<map object at 0x000001F7A520D9C8>" in the column "d" equivalent of my dataframe, which was causing issues. Happened when I was formatting text to title case using: *dfCM['Sector'] = map(lambda x: x.title(), dfCM['Sector'])*. I've now gone with *dfCM['Sector'] = dfCM['Sector'].str.title()* While not ideal as it capitalizes conjunctions, i don't get an error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work,

```
import numpy as np

df['e'] = np.where(df['a'] == 1, "Err :" + df['c'] + "-" + df['d'], np.NaN)
```

---

```
   a   c   d           e
0  1  ab  xy  Err :ab-xy
1  0  cd  zf         NaN
2  0  sd  zk         NaN
3  1  df  sd  Err :df-sd
```